# R files with Jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have just started to run the R kernel with Jupyter lab. How can I can import existing .R files into a jupyter notebook.
Also I can I save a .jpynb notebook back to .R if needed?

Rgs

CCR

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a `source("filename.R")` function could help.

Following R Documentation it

> "..causes R to accept its input from the named file or URL or connection or expressions directly. Input is read and parsed from that file until the end of the file is reached, then the parsed expressions are evaluated sequentially in the chosen environment".

Applying some parameters like *echo, keep.source, local* etc. to the function also seems useful.

Good luck!

P.S. I have no idea yet how to save .ipynb back to .R files